# Screen blinking occasionally

Tags: graphics, 22.04

This is my first time using Linux. I had Ubuntu 22.04 installed a few weeks and there has been many issues, but to start with, the screen blinks every few minutes - it goes black for a second then returns, seemingly randomly and without triggers. This happens every 2-10 minutes. I'm not sure what further information I need to provide.